# Elsword on Ubuntu

Tags: games, playonlinux

Can anyone help me?I downloaded Elsword with Playonlinux it worked very fine until "Mailmime.dll is missing" error popped out.Is there any way to fix it?I tried downloading Mailmime.dll but it didn't worked.Is there any other ways to download Elsword?

Comment: Nvm.I just learned that Wine doesn't supports GameGuard or Xtrap.So that detects I don't use Windows and corrupts the file. "-.-